# Explicit log file

Tags: magento-1.8, log

Is there a way to have an explicit excpetion.log file that gives you all the details and doesn't ommit anything with the (...) ?

> Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_control...', Array)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358464/387136

**Below a snippet from the answer**

I've added a function, which I got from **[Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418819/steve)** ([How can I get the full string of PHP’s getTraceAsString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949345/how-can-i-get-the-full-string-of-phps-gettraceasstring)) to `app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php`

```
    function getExceptionTraceAsString($exception) {
        $rtn = "";
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($exception->getTrace() as $frame) {
            $args = "";
            if (isset($frame['args'])) {
                $args = array();
                foreach ($frame['args'] as $arg) {
                    if (is_string($arg)) {
                        $args[] = "'" . $arg . "'";
                    } elseif (is_array($arg)) {
                        $args[] = "Array";
                    } elseif (is_null($arg)) {
                        $args[] = 'NULL';
                    } elseif (is_bool($arg)) {
                        $args[] = ($arg) ? "true" : "false";
                    } elseif (is_object($arg)) {
                        $args[] = get_class($arg);
                    } elseif (is_resource($arg)) {
                        $args[] = get_resource_type($arg);
                    } else {
                        $args[] = $arg;
                    }
                }
                $args = join(", ", $args);
            }
            $rtn .= sprintf( "#%s %s(%s): %s%s(%s)\n",
                $count,
                $frame['file'],
                $frame['line'],
                isset($frame['class']) ? $frame['class'] . '->' : '',
                $frame['function'],
                $args );
            $count++;
        }
        return $rtn;
    }
```

I've modified `Mage.php` file (*printException* method) - instead of `$e->getTraceAsString()` I've inserted `getExceptionTraceAsString($e)` - notice that there's two appearances: for Debug mode on, and off.

The above logic only modifies Error/report output; to add this logic to Exception log as well you'll want to modify the Mage::logException method - change

```
self::log("\n" . $e->__toString(), Zend_Log::ERR, $file);
```

with

```
self::log("\n" . $e->getMessage() . getExceptionTraceAsString($e), Zend_Log::ERR, $file);
```

Hope it helps!